# How do you calculate drive times around a point?

Tags: qgis, buffer, polygon-creation

For example, if I have an Airport point and I want to create a 30-minute Drive Times buffer polygon around it, how would I do that?

I'm currently using QGIS 3.4.4.

Comment: What data do you have at hand? Does it have to take current traffic into account? Do you want to take different vehicles into account?

Comment: @Erik this is a new area of spatial analysis for me, so I don't really know. Are there different ways of calculating this? A general estimation of drive times should be good for my purposes.

Comment: First of all you should have an idea, what you want to achieve. Then do some research on how it can be done and rather ask specific questions here, because currently the question is too broad.

Comment: @erik what information do you need to help narrow it down? it does not need to take current traffic into account and I am interested in cars

Comment: I want you to start thinking, what you need, what you already have and what exactly the output should be. As I said, currently your question is way too broad.

Comment: @erik the problem is I don't know what I don't know, so I don't know what I need. All I have is an airport point....

Comment: Then start by downloading QGIS.

Comment: @Erik he already stated that he has QGIS

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html - this should cover what you asked for exactly (esp. bulletin 7.3.6).

Answer (score 0):

@Erik

I use the OSM tools plugin, allows you to do ISOCHRONES up to 60minutes around a point.

You can get an API key for free through their website.